# Automatically toggle background data for a given app

Tags: mobile-data, automation, background-data

I have one app that "misbehaves" when on mobile data – ie. it takes quite big bites out of my battery. I don't want to cut it off from mobile data completely, though – as I need it from time to time and also want to get information on data incoming to it.

I know I could use Greenify and Tasker (see: [Hibernate apps, but have them wake up periodically for a short time](/q/179693/16575)), but that approach is a bit heavy-handed: Each time when I bring the app to foreground, it populates the screen fresh as if I had just started it.

> What I'd very much like is something along the lines of using Tasker to periodically cut off background data ***just for this app*** (note the approach to [Automatically restrict apps background data using Tasker](/q/89690/16575) is different, as it disables background data ***for all apps*** which is not what I want).

Are there any options I'm not aware of – like some "system call" (aka "shell exec") I could perform from Tasker?

In case it's relevant: root available, also Magisk, Xposed, and of course Tasker.

Comment: I just see AFWall+ offers Tasker support. If anyone has experience with that and thinks it's a viable option, details are welcome :)

Comment: You can apply an AFwall+ profile through Tasker. Very easy and works well. But, do you use blacklist or whitelist approach in AFwall+?

Comment: @Firelord yupp, found that approach [as recipe on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/5pxm8l/howto_avoid_data_leaks_when_connecting_to_an_open/). Just unsure if that improves the situation or makes it worse. With data toggled of situation would be clearer. // I don't use AFWall+ yet – but if, I had the Whitelist approach in mind. It's the safer one, think of new installs.

Answer (score 1):

Tasker now has this inbuilt!

`Actions->Net->Network access`

It allows per-app or global settings.

Comment: Thanks – close, but no cigar. That's not just background data, but network access at all (i.e. also with the app in forground, and also on WiFi). Could be partially worked around by conditions (`IF %WIFII !~ *CONNECTION*` plus "if not {app}" so it does not apply with the app in foreground or while connected to a WiFi – the latter might need a plugin like [AppContext](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.shortway.appcontext) (root, Xposed) to work correctly).